# Python-like dictionary in latex?

Tags: code

Is there a command/macro in `latex` to generate `python`-like dictionaries, i.e.

```
var = {a:1, b:2, c:3}
```

which then return for `\var{b}` `2`?

Comment: If you use numeric keys you can use the TeX primitive \ifcase ... \or: \def\var#1{\ifcase 1 a\or b\or c}

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can emulate it with a property list:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\DefineDictionary}{mm}
 {
  \arclupus_dict_def:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__arclupus_dict_temp_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \arclupus_dict_def:nn
 {
  \prop_gclear_new:c { g_arclupus_#1_dict_prop }
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \__arclupus_dict_add:nn { #1 } { ##1 }
   }
  \cs_new:cpn { #1 } ##1 { \prop_item:cn { g_arclupus_#1_dict_prop } { ##1 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__arclupus_dict_add:nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__arclupus_dict_temp_seq { / } { #2 }
  \prop_gput:cxx { g_arclupus_#1_dict_prop }
   {
    \seq_item:Nn \l__arclupus_dict_temp_seq { 1 }
   }
   {
    \seq_item:Nn \l__arclupus_dict_temp_seq { 2 }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_gput:Nnn { cxx }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DefineDictionary{var}{a/1, b/2, c/3}

\begin{document}

\var{a}

\var{c}

\var{b}

\end{document}
```

The `\DefineDictionary` takes as argument the dictionary name and the data. A new property list is created (or an existing one is cleared); then each item in the second argument is split at `/` to become an item in the property list. Finally, a macro with the name of the dictionary is created to retrieve the data.

The version with the colon is slightly trickier, because we can't use a literal `:` for the split operation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\DefineDictionary}{mm}
 {
  \arclupus_dict_def:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__arclupus_dict_temp_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \arclupus_dict_def:nn
 {
  \prop_gclear_new:c { g_arclupus_#1_dict_prop }
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \__arclupus_dict_add:nn { #1 } { ##1 }
   }
  \cs_new:cpn { #1 } ##1 { \prop_item:cn { g_arclupus_#1_dict_prop } { ##1 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__arclupus_dict_add:nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:NVn \l__arclupus_dict_temp_seq \c_colon_str { #2 }
  \prop_gput:cxx { g_arclupus_#1_dict_prop }
   {
    \seq_item:Nn \l__arclupus_dict_temp_seq { 1 }
   }
   {
    \seq_item:Nn \l__arclupus_dict_temp_seq { 2 }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { NV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_gput:Nnn { cxx }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DefineDictionary{var}{a:1, b:2, c:3}

\begin{document}

\var{a}

\var{c}

\var{b}

\end{document}
```

If you also need to pass macros to `\var`, then change the line

```
  \cs_new:cpn { #1 } ##1 { \prop_item:cn { g_arclupus_#1_dict_prop } { ##1 } }
```

into

```
  \cs_new:cpn { #1 } ##1 { \prop_item:cf { g_arclupus_#1_dict_prop } { ##1 } }
```

and add, just before `\ExplSyntaxOff`, the magic line

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_item:Nn { cf }
```

that defines the required variant.

Macros that expand to strings are then welcome in the argument of the newly created macro (`\var` in the example). Note that `\var` is still fully expandable.

Comment: You could add the `{a:1, b:2}` version. With the recent (or not so recent) `\char_generate:nn` and a `\seq_set_split:Nfn` it's relatively simple.

Comment: @Manuel Done; no `\char_generate:nn`, though. ;-)

Comment: I see it already exists :)

Comment: Going to test that, will report back, thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to get `\var{\mysinglelettermacro}` working? Right now it just prints nothing. (Assuming the `\var` from the above MWE).

Comment: @PTNobel Added; please let me know if you have problems.

Comment: This is incredible, Alleluiah!! You solved a problem I had for the last 30 years: how to build dictionaries in LaTeX witout using zillions of `\def\csname…\endcsname`…

Comment: @yannis Property lists are less efficient than using hash memory (like for `\csname...\endcsname`) when the properties are many. It's not really difficult to implement property lists with control sequence names, if needed.

Comment: @egreg I use them for footnote numbers: I have a script that fetches footnote IDs from DVI/XDV files and writes the dictionary, which is then read on the next run, and every footnote has the right number…

Comment: As usual, excellent answer! I wonder if it is possible use the `cf` variant and insert `\DefineDictionary{var}{a:1, b:2, c:3}` within the `\ExplSyntaxOn ... \ExplSyntaxOff` block.

Comment: @M.AlJumaily I wouldn’t do it, because that declaration belongs to the user level.

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, ConTeXt has built-in data-structure that is equivalent to a dictionary. In particular,

```
\setvariables
    [var]
    [
      a=1,
      b=2,
      c=3,
    ]
```

Then you can access the variables using `\getvariable{var}{a}`, etc.

Using `\def\abc{a} \getvariable{var}{\abc}` also works.